# How to get correct miliseconds from a DateTime object

Tags: android, datetime

I have a `Date` object in an objectify entity in the **backend module** of my android project.

when i try to access this object from my **app module**, it is returned as a `com.google.api.client.util.DateTime` object.

**In my backend module**

```
@Entity
public class MessageEntity{

 Date time;
 String message;

 public MessageEntity(){
 time = new Date();
 }

 public Date getDate(){
 return time;
 }
 //other geters and setters
}
```

**in another backend class method**

```
 public GetMessagesResponse getMessages(Context context, GetMessagesRequest req) throws NotFoundException, BadRequestException {

    com.googlecode.objectify.cmd.Query<MessageEntity> query = ofy().load().type(MessageEntity.class);

    query = query.order("dateCreated");

    List<MessageListItem> records = new ArrayList<>();
    QueryResultIterator<MessageEntity> iterator = query.iterator();
    int num = 0;
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        MessageEntity t = iterator.next();
        boolean position = false;

        MessageListItem i = new MessageListItem(position);
        i.setMessage(t.getMessage());
        i.setDateCreated(t.getDateCreated());
        i.setMessageId(t.getId());

        }
    }

    GetMessagesResponse res = new GetMessagesResponse();
    res.setSuccess(true);
    res.setMessages(CollectionResponse.<MessageListItem>builder().setItems(records).build());
    return res;

}
```

**This is how i access backend module data in my app module class**

```
private void loadConversationFromDb(){
    d("loadConversationFromDb");
    GetMessagesTask task = new GetMessagesTask(new ApiTask.ResultListener() {
        @Override
        public void successHook(Object o) {
            if (o instanceof GetMessagesResponse) {
                GetMessagesResponse res = (GetMessagesResponse) o;
                List<ChatMessageData> messages = new ArrayList<>();


                if (res.getMessages() != null) {
                    for (MessageListItem i : res.getMessages().getItems()) {
                        ChatMessageData dp = new ChatMessageData(i.getPosition(),
 i.getMessage(), /*THIS RETURNS A DATETIME object*/ i.getDateCreated());
                        messages.add(dp);
                    }
                }
```

i then access milliseconds from now DateTime object and format it in  a user frendly manner and set it as a string on TextView named `text_view_time`

```
 SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    DateTime time = provider.date;
    text_view_time.setText(dateFormat.format(new java.util.Date(time.getValue())));
```

**RESULT:**    `6 Nov 2015 14:29:07`

When user clicks on this textview, i get the time stamp and convert it in miliseconds

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    String time = text_view_time.getText().toString();
    Date date = dateFormat.parse(time);
    long miliseconds = date.getTime();
```

**PROBLEM**

The milliseconds that am getting from conversation of String in text view **DOES NOT** match the actual miliseconds that i got from **DATETIME** object.

**DATETIME object miliseconds:**   `1351700038292`

**Miliseconds obtained from string conversation**    `1351342452745`

**Question**
How can i correctly get miliseconds from a DateTime instance?

Comment: Sounds like a parsing issue. Did you try to convert milliseconds back to string to see what dates 1351700038292 and 1351342452745 are? It can be a timezone misinterpreting.

Comment: @ChristianB.Almeida is there a way to get lid of that time zone misinterpreting?

Comment: Have you confirmed if it's a timezone issue?

Comment: @ChristianB.Almeida   **DateTime** miliseconds is : `1444320105847` **its time stamp is**   `8 Oct 2015 19:01:45`.  **Date** milseconds is `1444320105000` its time stamp is `8 Oct 2015 19:01:45`.             seems like i can't use this to perform query in the database.  can you notice the difference btw milliseconds?  **its the last 4 digits!**

Comment: It will be different in last 3 digits FOR SURE!!! When you convert from string timestamp back to a date type, it truncates to "000" just because there is not MILISECONDS in "8 Oct 2015 19:01:45" text.

Comment: @ChristianB.Almeida  Is there any method or formula that you know can help in this?